# String concatenation error? [PHP]

Tags: php

i want to upload and then move a video to a directory i just created. Instead of moving the video to **/var/www/html/ProductVideos/lazar108@hotmail.com** it sends the video to **/var/www/html/ProductVideos/**

It works if i make $location = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/lazar108@hotmail.com" but the location will change so i am trying to make the PHP script dynamic

> ProductAccountName = lazar108@hotmail.com

Before PHP:
[image]

After PHP:
[image]

PHP code:

```
<?php

$ProductAccountName = $_POST['ProductAccountName'];

$NewDirectory = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/" . $ProductAccountName;

if (!file_exists($NewDirectory))
    {
        mkdir($NewDirectory, 0777, true);
    }

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

$location = $NewDirectory . $file_name; //"/var/www/html/ProductVideos/$ProductAccountName/" . $file_name;

move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `$_POST['ProductAccountName']` is not set, so following code

```
$ProductAccountName = $_POST['ProductAccountName'];

$NewDirectory = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/" . $ProductAccountName;
```

causes `$ProductAccountName` to be empty. Make sure you add

```
<input type="text" name="ProductAccountName" value="lazar108@hotmail.com">
```

inside your HTML form.

Comment: well if that was the case then the new directory wouldnt be made

Comment: try `print($location);` just to make sure it points to correct directory.

Comment: i am actually not using HTML so i couldnt do that :/

Comment: This isnt the correct answer but it got me thinking and i figured it out myself

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no `/` after `$ProductAccountName` in creating `$NewDirectory` variable. Try rewerite `location` like this:

```
$location = $NewDirectory . '/' . $file_name;
```

Comment: i think its something like that but that didnt fix it

Comment: So what is in `$location` variable?